# First Lua program--formatting text, color, background

Tags: arrays, text, printing, lua, format

I'm brand new here, and also to Lua, so please bear with me...

I'm building an Airport in Minecraft, with my kids. I'm an overachiever and a dreamer, and at some point, my brain decided it would be a FANTASTIC idea to add in a cosmetic element that I have absolutely NO idea how to do.  Smart, right?!

See,  I got it in my head that I want to have display screens in our Airport that show the flight information of incoming/outgoing flights.  Fast forward to my discovery of the Opencomputers mod for Minecraft, a few hours of watching tutorials on how to operate it, and thus began my search for knowledge of that which is the Lua language.  Fortunately, I have a wee bit of coding experience (thanks to my college days) and I picked up the very basic of the basics. (It seems similar to C.) I've gleaned just enough to accomplish the bigger part of my goal: I've managed to write the bare bones of the program I dreamed up, and it works...for the most part. (I still need to figure out some redundancies and such...all in good time.)

But...it's so very plain, and not fancy at all. It doesn't look even remotely like what I was picturing in my head, and this simply will not do. So now I am on a quest to discover how to format the output of my program and make it look fantastic...or at least, as close as I can get it to what was in my head.  I have managed to figure out how to change the gpu screen colors (foreground, background) so that is why it's blue/white.  But it's not quite what I wanted, and it resets if the system is turned off.  My goal is to change the format of the program output itself, not just the Opencomputers screen block.  I've googled this until I'm blue in the face, and I have pored over forums and code tutorials and the like...only to fail at finding the information I need.  It's possible that I've passed up the answer, simply because I'm still very new to the language, but that's another good reason for me to be here, right?

And so, I turn to you, O Great Dwellers of the Interwebs, the Keepers of Vast Programming Knowledge, for assistance.  Please, pretty please, help me make my program look awesome. My kids just may think I'm the coolest Mom on the planet, and that would be more than fantastic...Not to mention we'd have one kickass airport to play around in. :)

Here's what you'll probably want to know:

First,  [This pic is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TanGq.png), (on the left) and what I have (on the right).

And here is the code for my program:  http://pastebin.com/60nPfpB8

I apologize up front for all of the noob mistakes that my code is more than likely riddled with.  I haven't figured out yet how to make the functions repeat themselves, or a good way to utilize a 24 hour clock for the "time" function.  So any suggestions there would be welcome as well.

Thank you for taking the time to read, and I appreciate any help I can get with this.   :)

Comment: I do not think that somebody in this forum faced mine craft lua.

Comment: Check this http://computercraft.info/wiki/Term.setBackgroundColor

Comment: And this http://www.computercraft.info/forums2/index.php?/topic/10180-luaquestion/

Comment: @Vyacheslav given the number of users on stackoverflow and the popularity of minecraft it is pretty naive to think that no one here has faced mine craft lua...

Comment: @Vyacheslav  Hi, From what I have read while digging around, Computercraft and Opencomputers don't use the same syntax...I read both of those posts and the first one you suggested basically says how to do what I've already done on OpenComputers, which is change the background/text colors of the terminal itself. What I'm trying to do is print the results of the random arrays, on different lines with different colored background...like a chart, perhaps. The second one is again, for computercraft, which is different... But thank you for reading my post and trying. :)